# Read in zlib file in Python results in "incorrect header check"

Tags: python, compression, zlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [uncompressing tar.Z file with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272199/uncompressing-tar-z-file-with-python)

I am trying to read a zlib compressed in order to directly access the data in the contained HDF file (using pyhdf). However, I always receive an error message. Here is the [file](ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/ftp/data/s4pa//TRMM_L3/TRMM_3B42/2007/001/3B42.20070101.03.7A.HDF.Z).

```
import zlib
file = open('3B42.20070101.00.7A.HDF.Z','rb')
data = zlib.decompress(file.read())

>> error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

I checked several other ways (e.g. gzip.open/gzip.zlib) but nothing seems to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a zlib or gzip file, it's compressed by the old Unix tool `compress` (as you can tell from the `.Z` extension). The command-line tools `gzip`/`gunzip`/`zcat` can read those, but not the Python `gzip` module. You could use a pipe:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

filename = "3B42.20070101.03.7A.HDF.Z"
f = Popen(["zcat", filename], stdout=PIPE).stdout
```

Now, `f` is a file-like that can be used to read the file.

Comment: Beat me to it +1 (can just use `uncompress filename` instead of gzip with params though...)

Comment: @JonClements: changed it to use `zcat`, which is shorter still.